# Electric Universe: planetary system inside a Red Star

Tags: internal-consistency, evolution, alternate-reality, electromagnetism

Based on the [Electric Universe physics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plasma_cosmology) a Red Star could harbor a planetary system within. How would life evolve taking in account that light would be almost constant in all the planets contained by the star. In doubt, let's assume conditions are equal to our universe, but with a constant stream of energy in the surface of the planets.

Comment: Hello Tomás!  As you might imagine, we're barely beginning to understand our own evolution.  Asking us to explain how something would evolve in a postulated cosmology is too broad and primarily opinion based.  Is it possible to considerably narrow the question?

Comment: I agree of course, the idea is to think of it as the-same-but-with-lots of light. I will edit that.

Comment: I am not familiar with Electric Universe, but would be curious to see how this theory prevents planetary orbits swallowed by a red giant star from decaying.

Comment: @Alexander makes a point, but I suspect you don't want us caught up in the back story.  Perhaps one more edit that explains the Electric Universe cosmology is your reference, but your question is fundamentally independent (and you need to be VERY SPECIFIC because the evolution of all things is much too broad). So, maybe, "How might a human-like creature's evolution be different from our own given the evolutionary pressure of constant light?"

Comment: I assume you are talking about gravity force, they don't. Gravity as a cosmological force in negligeable in the Electric Universe Model.

Comment: This would be not so much about gravity as about the atmospheric drag.

Answer (score 1):

The surface of a red star will be at around 3000 Kelvin, which is hot enough to melt [any elements except tungsten, carbon, rhenium, osmium, and tantalum](https://www.lenntech.com/periodic-chart-elements/melting-point.htm). In fact, everything except carbon and a slightly larger array of metals will have [boiled away](https://www.lenntech.com/periodic-chart-elements/boiling-point.htm) by 3000 K. Most chemical compounds will have denatured long before that.

An added difficulty here is that although there will be plenty of energy present in the form of heat, that doesn't make it *useful* energy. Loosely speaking, using thermal energy (including radiant heat) to do useful work requires a temperature differential; plants can photosynthesise because sunlight is thousands of degrees "hotter" than the plant's ambient temperature, but when everything is at the same 3000 Kelvin it's impossible to make use of that heat.

If life exists under those conditions, it will not be remotely as we know it. Best option is to hand-wave about exotic states of matter, especially since plasma cosmology already takes this into fringe-theory territory.